# Mapping CSV to nested POCO elements using CSVHelper

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I have an old legacy database which has been converted to a CSV, where I am trying to parse and break down the data using `CSVHelper` in order to seed the new database (using entity framework).

For example I have the following CSV headers;

`Rec,ID,FirstName,Lastname,Email,BusinessPhone,Company,JobTitle,HomePhone,MobilePhone,FaxNumber,Address,City,State,PostalCode,Country,WebPage,Term,Website,CompanyReg,YearEstablished,AgreementNumber,ExpiryDate`

(This is a reduce for brevity)

Under the new system we have the following POCO maps (again reduced for brevity);

```
public class Company 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Website { get; set; }

    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }

    public IList<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
}

public class Address 
{
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string Address3 { get; set; }
    public string Town { get; set; }
    public string Region { get; set; }
    public string PostCode { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public bool IsPrimaryAddress { get; set; }

}

public class Contact 
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string HomeTelephone { get; set; }
    public string BusinessTelephone { get; set; }
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public bool IsPrimaryContact { get; set; }
}
```

My mappers are then as follows;

```
public sealed class CompanyMap : ClassMap<Company>
{
    public CompanyMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.Id).Name("ID");
        Map(m => m.Name).Name("Company");
        Map(m => m.Website).Name("WebPage");

        References<CompanyAddressFromCompanyMap>(m => m.Address);

        References<PrimaryContactFromCompanyMap>(m => m.Contacts);
    }
}

public sealed class CompanyAddressFromCompanyMap: ClassMap<Address>
{
    public CompanyAddressFromCompanyMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.Address1).Name("Address");
        Map(m => m.Town).Name("City");
        Map(m => m.Region).Name("State");
        Map(m => m.PostCode).Name("PostalCode");
        Map(m => m.Country).Name("Country");
        Map(m => m.IsPrimaryAddress).Default(true);
    }
}

public sealed class PrimaryContactFromCompanyMap : ClassMap<Contact>
{
    public PrimaryContactFromCompanyMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.FirstName).Name("FirstName");
        Map(m => m.LastName).Name("LastName");
        Map(m => m.HomeTelephone).Name("HomePhone");
        Map(m => m.BusinessTelephone).Name("BusinessPhone");
        Map(m => m.Mobile).Name("MobilePhone");
        Map(m => m.Email).Name("Email");
        Map(m => m.IsPrimaryContact).Default(true);
    }
}
```

However this is throwing the error;

`System.ArgumentException: Property 'System.String FirstName' is not defined for type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[Contact]' (Parameter 'property')`

Which I assume is possibly due to this being a `IList<Contact>`?

Can anyone advise on the error and how I can map to the nested collections?

Answer (score 0):

The question was interesting.

I've removed some of the fields of the csv to simplify things.
I've just registered your `ClassMap<PrimaryContactFromCompanyMap>` in the configuration and used a simple `Map(m => m.Contacts).ConvertUsing( ...)`.

I was not able to figure how to use a `TypeConverter<T>` but this may works too.

Probably the best is to avoid to use `References<T>` to register a nested `classMap`, but instead register it directly in the configuration and use a simple `Map<T>`.

This is the complete *xunit* test example.

```
    public class CsvHelper
    {
        internal string csv = @"
Company,Address,FirstName,AnotherName
MyCompany,MyAddress,MyFirstName,MyAnotherName
";
        public CsvHelper()
        {

        }

        [Fact]
        public void Stackoverflow()
        {
            using var r = new StringReader(csv);
            var conf = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            conf.Delimiter = ",";
            conf.RegisterClassMap<CompanyMap>();
            conf.RegisterClassMap<PrimaryContactFromCompanyMap>();

            using var cr = new CsvReader(r, conf);
            var records = cr.GetRecords<Company>().ToList();
            Assert.True(records.Count == 1);
        }
    }

    public class Company
    {
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
        public Address Address { get; set; }

        public IList<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
    }

    public class Address
    {
        public string Address1 { get; set; }
    }


    public class Contact
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }

    public sealed class CompanyMap : ClassMap<Company>
    {
        public CompanyMap()
        {
            Map(m => m.CompanyName).Name("Company");

            References<CompanyAddressFromCompanyMap>(m => m.Address);
            Map(m => m.Contacts).ConvertUsing(r =>
            {
                var c = r.GetRecord<Contact>();
                return new List<Contact>() { c };
            });
        }
    }

    public sealed class CompanyAddressFromCompanyMap : ClassMap<Address>
    {
        public CompanyAddressFromCompanyMap()
        {
            Map(m => m.Address1).Name("Address");
        }
    }

    public sealed class PrimaryContactFromCompanyMap : ClassMap<Contact>
    {
        public PrimaryContactFromCompanyMap()
        {
            Map(m => m.FirstName).Name("FirstName");
            Map(m => m.LastName).Name("AnotherName");
        }
    }
}
```